# Applying subdivision adds too much geometry

Tags: subdivision-surface

When I apply the subdivision surface modifier it seems to add too much geometry, does this look normal to you?

I was doing a tutorial on another mesh and my mesh had way more geometry than the one in the tutorial, so I tested with a simple cube and got (I believe) way too much geometry again.

Before applying:

[image]

after applying:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal and expected. In fact that's exactly what the subdivision modifier does, it subdivides faces, adding geometry. It's just that the added geometry is not visible in wireframe until you apply it, unless you turn off "Optimal Display". Here's a subdivided cube to illustrate:

[image]

[image]

If you have more geometry than you need, just reduce the Viewport levels of the subdivision modifier before applying it. But of course the model won't look as smooth if it has less levels of subdivision, so you have to balance those two things.